# How to add a margin to an inner Angular Component using the CSS of the component that includes it

Tags: css, angular

One can see in the example https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples that material components can be styled using the CSS of the component that includes them:

```
.example-headers-align .mat-form-field + .mat-form-field {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

When trying to add a right margin to my-own-component with:

```
.example-headers-align .my-own-component {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Nothing happens :( Is the above wrong?

A small example of the question above consists of:

Included component *my-own-component.component.html*:

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Running</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Parent component *my-panel.component.html*:

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="example-headers-align">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title><strong>System 123</strong></mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            22 queues, 2 nodes
        </mat-panel-description>

        <my-own-component></my-own-component>

    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    More details here ...
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

... and the style customization for the parent component *my-panel.component.css*:

```
.example-headers-align .mat-expansion-panel-header-title,
.example-headers-align .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  flex-basis: 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.example-headers-align .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.example-headers-align {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.example-headers-align .my-own-component {
    margin-right: 3rem;
}
```

No margin gets applied as seen on [image]

For more details the codebase is available from https://github.com/adelinor/add-margin-example#setup-steps-and-margin-display-issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a more complete example of the issue? like a [mcve]

Comment: Dear @blurfus , many thanks for your help. I added a link to a small example illustrating the issue

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the code here instead? - we do not need the entire code base, just a [mcve]

Comment: Dear @blurfus, please find the minimal example above.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the styles in the root file styles.css

I've found that when adding components with classes not directly in the html template, adding them in the global styles.css gets it working

Comment: Brilliant! Just moving the CSS configuration to styles.css  (or a parent of my-panel in the example) solves the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    .example-headers-align { position: relative;}

    .example-headers-align .my-own-component {
      margin-right: 8px;
      position: absolute;
     }
```

Comment: `position: absolute` could affect other things in the component.  It is not necessary